# Chaining the checkbox animation using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am new to CSS Animations and am trying to chain animation of checkboxes being checked. Basically, I have a list of Items and corresponding checkboxes. My aim is to start checking the checkboxes one after the other.

I have done the checking animation (animated tick) with the help of few online tutorials. Though now I am unable to figure out a way to replicate the clicking event of checkboxes to start the animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/vishsid73/a7L5kdvL/2/

```css
@-moz-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}

input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }

.check-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check-box::before,
.check-box::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #23527c;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease .5;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease .5;
  transition: opacity ease .5;
}

.check-box::before {
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
/*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #667788;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.check-box::after {
/*  top: 37px; */
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0px;
/*  left: 5px;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box,
.check-box.checked { border-color: #23527c; }

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::after,
.check-box.checked::after {
/*  height: 50px;*/
  height: 25px;
  -moz-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::before,
.check-box.checked::before {
/*  height: 120px;*/
  height: 70px;
  -moz-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Sid Anim</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest" />
    <label for="cbtest" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest1" />
    <label for="cbtest1" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest2" />
    <label for="cbtest2" class="check-box"></label>
    
</div>
</body>
```

Please Guide how to chain the animation with 1.5 sec gap after previous

Comment: You would need javascript to do this. CSS can't check something that isn't checked.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ya. but then via javascript how do I use animation delay like : #anim1                  { animation-delay:1s, 1s; -moz-animation-delay:1s,1s; -webkit-animation-delay:1s,1s; }. Is there any other way.

Comment: You don't. You apply delays inside the javascript loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to be any JQuery expert but you can do it like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cbtest').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function(i) {
      var myDelay = 500
      var myElement = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        myElement.prop('checked', true);
      }, i * myDelay);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@-moz-keyframes dothabottomcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dothabottomcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@keyframes dothabottomcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@keyframes dothatopcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dothatopcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes dothatopcheck {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.check-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.check-box::before,
.check-box::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #23527c;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease .5;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease .5;
  transition: opacity ease .5;
}
.check-box::before {
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  /*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #667788;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.check-box::after {
  /*  top: 37px; */
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  /*  left: 5px;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box,
.check-box.checked {
  border-color: #23527c;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::after,
.check-box.checked::after {
  /*  height: 50px;*/
  height: 25px;
  -moz-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::before,
.check-box.checked::before {
  /*  height: 120px;*/
  height: 70px;
  -moz-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Sid Anim</h2>

    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest" />
    <label for="cbtest" class="check-box"></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest1" />
    <label for="cbtest1" class="check-box"></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest2" />
    <label for="cbtest2" class="check-box"></label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Man :-) I removed the $('#cbtest').click(function() {}); for auto starting the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using your current CSS animations by checking the checkboxes with a delay, using Javascript...

**JQuery Version**
If you are already using jQuery on your page...

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i) {
    var item = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        item.prop('checked','checked');
    }, 1000*i);
});
```

```css
@-moz-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}

input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }

.check-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check-box::before,
.check-box::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #23527c;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease .5;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease .5;
  transition: opacity ease .5;
}

.check-box::before {
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
/*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #667788;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.check-box::after {
/*  top: 37px; */
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0px;
/*  left: 5px;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box,
.check-box.checked { border-color: #23527c; }

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::after,
.check-box.checked::after {
/*  height: 50px;*/
  height: 25px;
  -moz-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::before,
.check-box.checked::before {
/*  height: 120px;*/
  height: 70px;
  -moz-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Sid Anim</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest" />
    <label for="cbtest" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest1" />
    <label for="cbtest1" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest2" />
    <label for="cbtest2" class="check-box"></label>
    
</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript Version**
If you need a vanilla js solution...

```js
checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i < checkboxes.length;i++) {
    doSetTimeout(i)
}

function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
      checkboxes[i].checked = true;
  }, 1000*i);
}
```

```css
@-moz-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 25px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 70px;
}
}

input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }

.check-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  transition: border-color ease 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check-box::before,
.check-box::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #23527c;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease .5;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease .5;
  transition: opacity ease .5;
}

.check-box::before {
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
/*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #667788;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.check-box::after {
/*  top: 37px; */
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0px;
/*  left: 5px;*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box,
.check-box.checked { border-color: #23527c; }

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::after,
.check-box.checked::after {
/*  height: 50px;*/
  height: 25px;
  -moz-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothabottomcheck 0.2s ease 0s forwards;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box::before,
.check-box.checked::before {
/*  height: 120px;*/
  height: 70px;
  -moz-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Sid Anim</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest" />
    <label for="cbtest" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest1" />
    <label for="cbtest1" class="check-box"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtest2" />
    <label for="cbtest2" class="check-box"></label>
    
</div>
</body>
```